# Description directly input into schema file for sql server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server-2008, schema, data-dictionary

My boss is asking me to find an easy way for the engineers to type in descriptions of entities and fields of a large database (sql server 2008) and I am struggling to understand his requirement. He mentioned there is a way of doing so by "directly inputting descriptions in the schema files in a specific syntax that other software can easily pull out to generate a data dictionary".

He said this is what he did 7 / 8 years ago and it was very easy

I looked on the web, and I showed him how you can use SQL statements to edit the external properties of entities and fields, to which he said it was not what he wanted and that "this is not a convenient or fast way" of doing so.

Does any one know what my boss is talking about? And maybe explain to me what sort of schema file he is talking about?

Comment: If you want easy input then http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/ is pretty slick for editing the extended properties on a running database. (Just make sure you hit the little save button).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way that has ever existed for SQL Server other than sp_addextendedproperty when it comes to schema definition. In Enterprise Manager, it used to be a little more obvious how to enter in descriptions. In Management Studio, it's really non obvious. You can do it a little easier if you create a database diagram, then edit the custom view of the tables and add the description column to the view. You could also use a tool like http://www.sqldatadictionary.com to quickly edit many descriptions.